# How to install the richdocuments plugin on Owncloud?

Tags: server, libreoffice, owncloud-server

I'm trying to install this plugin: https://github.com/owncloud/richdocuments on Owncloud 9 on Ubuntu server 16.04 64bit.

Can someone tell me how to install this app?'

The main area of confusion for me is that it mentions LibreOffice Online WebSocket Daemon (loolwsd), but it isn't clear if this is included or not.

Comment: On which part you struggle? compiling, packing or other?

Comment: @Videonauth time. I am too busy with other aspects of managing 3 servers to spend time figuring out this particular plugin which the developer SHOULD have posted on the standard repository like everyone else does...

Comment: Just give me the bounty :-P

Comment: @TheXed when you have delivered the fugitive!

Comment: I have, His name is @Videonauth. See below.

Comment: @TheXed okay I will give you the 10 000 dollars. Guyanese dollars }:>

Comment: Hey that is like 50 USD...I'll take it!

Answer (score 5):

*For the following process I assume you have an already working and running* `owncloud-server` *installation on your server. I have tested this on a VM with 16.04 LTS server, so no fancy own configurations, you may have to adapt that to fit your situation.*

**1. Preparation:**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git libtool m4 autoconf automake libpng12-dev libcap-dev libpoco-dev
```

**2. Creation of the distribution:**

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/owncloud/richdocuments.git
cd richdocuments/
make dist
```

**3. Installation of what we just created:**

```
sudo apt-get install php-apcu
cd /var/www/owncloud/apps/
sudo tar -xf ~/richdocuments/owncloud-collabora-online-0.15.1.tar.gz
sudo mv owncloud-collabora-online-0.15.1/ richdocuments/
cd ../../config
sudo nano config.php
```

Add this line:

```
'memcache.local' => '\OC\Memcache\APCu'
```

After that:

```
cd ..
sudo ./occ app:enable richdocuments
```

**Note:** `loolwsd` is not included in the bundle you can get it with `git clone https://github.com/LibreOffice/online.git`, please refer to the `README` in the `loolwsd` subdirectory on how to build and setup. After that build `loleaflet` as well.

You need to configure the WOPI Client URL, which is where the LibreOffice Online WebSocket Daemon (loolwsd) is listening.

```
sudo ./occ config:app:set --value='https://<hostname or IP address>:<port>' richdocuments wopi_url
```

Default port is 9980. If `loolwsd` was compiled without SSL, you have to write http instead of https. If you use SSL, and you get the following error:

```
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

You have to add the CA cert manually to ownCloud trusted cert storage:

```
sudo cat ca-chain.cert.pem >> owncloud/resources/config/ca-bundle.crt
```

Comment: This not an answer since he is asking directly about that certain plugin.

Comment: He was asking if this plugin is included in richdocuments, and it is not. By the way a supercomplete build description on those twoo too would probably bust the 19,5k char limit on answers. So i rather wait untill i get a response from the OP.

Comment: That's where he points so he can get help to install the whole thing. But... he asked "Can someone tell me how to install this app?'" His process falls on both the scope of the LIbreOffice(WebSocket wtv) and OwnCloud(plugin). Actually the plugin is useless without the Libre Office Daemon.

Comment: Ah yes and the libreoffice daemon needs `libpoco` and this needs again something, what do you think where should it stop ? maybe building the whole toolchain again and make an own linux out of it ?

Comment: Okay will likely try this tomorrow. Thanks for your answer. I was going to try running through the instructions on the readme myself but I was busy with a lot of other things. Good on you for testing it btw.

I'll grant you the bounty if it works :)

Comment: If you need more detailed steps just drop me a line in AU general chat. I'll will work then on it.

Comment: Looks like I may be delayed in trying this - we'll see how it goes.

Comment: Just holler if your stuck or something.